# How to build ACE wrappers for 32bit platform?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tao

I've recently downloaded the latest distribution (2.2a) of the Ace ORB (TAO) from OCI and I've been trying to unsuccessfully build it with Visual Studio 2008, in Debug mode for the 32bit platform. If I try to build it 64bit it runs just fine however in 32bit it fails.
In recent time I've successfully built the version 1.6a in Debug mode for the 32 bit platform in the same machine but now it doesn't seem to be working.
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Here is part of the error list when I try to build:

```
Error   843 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'async_iortable_export.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\tao\iortable\Locate_ResponseHandler.h    

Error   1159    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1161    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1164    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1167    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1176    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1182    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1186    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\utils.h 

Error   1194    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImplRepoC.h': No such file or directory   c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Server_Info.h   

Error   1201    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_ActivatorC.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Activator_Info.h    

Error   1139    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_ActivatorS.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\ImR_Activator_i.h   

Error   1141    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_ActivatorS.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\ImR_Activator_i.h   

Error   1196    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_ActivatorS.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\AsyncAccessManager.h    

Error   1235    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_ActivatorS.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\ImR_Activator_i.h   

Error   1240    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_ActivatorS.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\ImR_Activator_i.h   

Error   1195    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_LocatorC.h': No such file or directory    c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\AsyncListManager.h  

Error   1169    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImR_LocatorS.h': No such file or directory    c:\winrios\common\ace_wrappers\tao\orbsvcs\implrepo_service\Replicator.h    

Error   1246    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'orbsvcs/AVStreamsC.h': No such file or directory  c:\winrios\Common\ACE_wrappers\TAO\orbsvcs\orbsvcs\AV\AV_Core.h
```

Comment: These are all tao_idl generated files. Do you have compiled tao_idl and can you execute it?

Comment: I opened the solution TAO_ACE_vc8 again and first I successfully rebuilt  the TAO_Core_idl_vc8 project, then I tried to build the entire solution again and the same problem happened. How should I proceed to execute the tao_idl to see if everything is ok? Assuming tao_idl was successfully built could some of the compiled files be placed in the wrong folder?

Comment: Try first TAO 6.4.0 which you can download from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu. Make sure ACE_wrappers/lib is in your path.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help! I tried to use that exact version of TAO in the past, however it only works with Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 which causes me compatibility issues because my project is old and was created with the Visual Studio 2008 Platform Toolset (v90).

Comment: With 6.4.0 you have to generate the msvc solutions yourself but after that step it should work

Comment: Hi Johnny, once again thanks for your fast reply. You are right 6.4.0 works, my assumption that TAO 6.4.0 could not be compiled with Visual Studio's Platform toolset v90 because it was a VS2015 project was wrong. 
However after some research, instead of generating the msvc solution I found out that if I installed VS2010 I would be able to compile the TAO project with the v90 toolset because because it has the appropriate MSBuild scripts that enable targeting VS 2008 (they only ship with VS 2010).

Comment: The successful build I mentioned before was only relative to ACE solution, however when I try to compile TAO_ACE in 32bit in Debug mode, it fails even if I use the latest platform toolset from Visual Studio (v140). The problem still appears to be related with TAO_idl.